# How can I trigger a job after 15 minutes in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, amazon-sqs, jobs

I need to create a job that is going to be trigger after 15 minutes a post is created, I can set 15 minutes of delay, but imagine that the job is going to take 1 minute to process, in total will be 16 minutes, but the problem is that in SQS the maximum time is 15 minutes, what can I do?

Comment: you can [delay](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queues#delayed-dispatching) a job to a certain time. If takes 1m you need to improve the job.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the requirement of the job completing every fifteen minutes (not just being triggered after fifteen minutes) you may want to look into webhooks, I don’t know if they would provide the solution that you need but it would allow the SQS end to query every fifteen minutes for the data and the timeout for completion on the post end would no longer be a factor.

A quick google led me to the following package which might be an answer for you
[palpalani/laravel-queue-json-reader](https://github.com/palpalani/laravel-sqs-queue-json-reader)